# How I can print informations about user (who is logged) in django template?

Tags: python, django

I have template like this :

```
<html>
<body>
You are logged as John Kowalski
</body>
</html>
```

I would like show first_name and last_name of user but this doesn't work:

```
<html>
<body>
You are logged as {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get user object in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

First, add the following to your settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request', 
)
```

(You can add other context processors, but this is the relevant one.)

Second, in your views:

Import this:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
```

And in your views, return your templates like this:

```
return render_to_response('something.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You can now access the `request` object in your template.

Learn more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Comment: or if django>=1.3 you can use the shortcut render: return render(request, 'template.path.html', {'foo':'bar'})